# Text file to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file containing 5 columns of data. The first column contains names and the following 4 are filled with numbers. How can I import the text file and convert each row into a dictionary item with the key as the name in the first column and the return value as the value in the third column?

Cheers

Comment: Are these fixed width columns or are they delimited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the columns are delimited by whitespace, you can do

```
d = {}
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, dummy, dummy, value, dummy = line.split()
        d[key] = float(value)
```

Comment: Knew it would be a nice simple solve. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a csv file:

```
with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    if you_have_header_row:
        next(reader)
    d = {row[0]:float(row[2]) for row in reader}
```